# SQLSTATE[42S22] : Column not found in my Laravel script

Tags: php, laravel

when I want see servicesList page, Laravel appear this error:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `services` where `category_id` = 29
>   and `user_id` is null) (View:
>   /.../core/resources/views/user/serviceList.blade.php) "

My serviceList codes:

```
@extends('user.layouts.master')
@section('site_title', 'Service List')
@section('page_title')
    <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i> @lang('slide.serviceslist')
@endsection
@section('body')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @foreach($categories as $category)
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white"> {{ $category->category->name ?? '' }}

                    </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>code</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Min</th>
                                <th>Max</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @php
                            $items = \App\ServicePrice::where('category_id', $category->category_id)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
                            @endphp
                            @foreach($items as $item)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $item->service_id ?? '' }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $item->service->name ?? ''}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $item->price ?? ''}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $item->service->min ?? ''}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $item->service->max ?? ''}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

ServiceList controller:

```
public function serviceList(){

    $categories = ServicePrice::where('user_id', Auth::id())->distinct()->get(['category_id']);
    return view('user.serviceList', compact('categories'));
}
```

ServicePrice model:

```
   namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class ServicePrice extends Model
   {
  public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
  }

   public function service(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Service::class, 'service_id', 'id');
   }
  }
```

Comment: I think you are using where clause wrong! Either make it array or use orWhere

`                            $items = \App\ServicePrice::where('category_id', $category->category_id)->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();` like `where([
       'column1' => value1,
       'column2' => value2,
       'column3' => value3
])`

Comment: I didn't change the code, in past it worked well but today I see this error

Comment: Check your table structure, does it have `user_id`? Or try hardcoding the `id` of the user, the `NULL` value may be interfering with the query.

Comment: I check it, there is Id for users table and it can't be null

Answer (score 0):

First you should check if you really have the user_id as a foreign key in your database table, just open your db interface like phpmyadmin and look if user_id is actually in the table. If it is in the table there is something wrong with your query.

This is your query:

```
ServicePrice::where('user_id', Auth::id())
            ->distinct()
            ->get(['category_id']);
```

Try to return `Auth::id()` just us `dd(Auth::id())` to see if there is actually a result for it or if it returns null. If i returns null I could be due to not being authentificated in your current application. `Auth::id()` only returns the id if the current user is authentificated. Just do that and tell me the result and we can further help.

Further check if `user_id` is in your fillable array in your service model.

Should look like this:

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id'];
```

Comment: I checked phpmyadmin and there is Id column for users table, and my authentificated is correct , I checked it with something and they don't sent an error for this problem!

Comment: the `user_id` has to be in your services table not in your users table `user_id` is a foreign key, also please check if user_id is in your fillables array in your service model

Comment: Sorry, Yes, my services has user_I'd to

Comment: What I should do with this code? : `protected $fillable = ['user_id']; `

Comment: @Amirhossein You are saving your data in your Service model or ServicePriceModel you need to define what you can actually sent to the model for security reason, if you add the `user_id` to the fillable array in your model it won't be ignored from saving, can you post your model to your question so I can have a look.

Comment: Sorry
What do you mean by model
Where is this file?

Comment: Hmm you should probably do some tutorials first I think if you do not know what a model is. This line: `$categories = ServicePrice::..` uses the ServicePrice class which is probably a class/model which you are someone else created, it is most likely located in App\ServicePrice.php

Comment: @Amirhossein no problem but I need to go soon I can probably help again in 10 hours (tomorrow) so you added the model, there is not $fillable array just add this:

`protected $fillable = ['field_1', 'field_2']` just add the field the name of your database columns into the array so if you have name in your table add 'name' to the array and so on.

Comment: I added servicePrice codes, please check it, sorry for my questions

Comment: Look you are beautiful, but you need to watch some tutorial first I think, your model has to look something like this: https://snipperino.io/snippets/lCQC2pKYBHWsnEiKNFQw4XgVcTb8QUYtvv5AQYeM, I am out for now I may help tomorrow bye